# How to get an input device that works both to record and output sound on Reaper and on the Internet

Tags: drivers, nvidia, pulseaudio, alsa, reaper

When I chose the Input device to be `sofhdadsp; sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp`, I have the following error message:

```
There was an error opening the audio hardware:

ALSA: error opening output device
```

And when I left it to `hw:NVidia ; HDA-INTEL - HDA NVidia` I have no issues arming an input track in Reaper but all the videos on Youtube freezed.

Is there a way to be both able to record sound on Reaper and have sound on Youtube videos ?

[image]

**Some additional informations**:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-GE66-Raider-11UH 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GE66 Raider 11UH v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-1543 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E1543IMS.119 date: 06/11/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 86.0 Wh (91.6%) condition: 93.9/95.0 Wh (98.9%)
    volts: 16.8 min: 15.2 model: MSI BIF0_9 status: Not charging
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-11800H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: L1: 640 KiB L2: 10 MiB L3: 24 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3611 high: 4258 min/max: 800/4600 cores: 1: 3975
    2: 2096 3: 4223 4: 4090 5: 3602 6: 3734 7: 4063 8: 4208 9: 4227 10: 1213
    11: 4244 12: 3603 13: 3262 14: 4258 15: 3929 16: 3058 bogomips: 73728
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 535.154.05 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-13:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 2560x1440~240Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-H HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-14-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek Killer E3000 2.5GbE vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169
    v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 2e:00.0
  IF: enp46s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz vendor: Rivet Networks
    driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 30:00.0
  IF: wlp48s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-7d0b39584f48 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX210 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-14:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.05 TiB used: 243.55 GiB (22.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVL21T0HCLR-00B00
    size: 953.87 GiB temp: 38.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/sda type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: SanDisk 3.2 Gen1
    size: 116.57 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 937.33 GiB used: 231.63 GiB (24.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 10 MiB (0.5%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 66.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 459 Uptime: 1d 19m Memory: 31.04 GiB used: 14.67 GiB (47.3%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2010 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```